# how to pass Json As a string through postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf, postman

I work on one WCF and accept json from different application , and store that json in to data base as a string, so when i try to pass json through POSTMAN for testing. i get null in method parameter.but if i pass simple string like "test" i got the value.

What i tried:
set header as content-type = application/json,
set POST request,add [httpppost] on method.

So i want to pass json as a string through POSTMAN. hope its help to understand my question.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: JSON is a textual format, so you always send it as a string. However, I don't completely understand the question. If you set `content-type` to `application/json`, you are saying "I'm sending JSON format" to the other side. `POST` method means "I'm sending data in HTTP body." I don't understand what "[httpppost] on method" means. "Pass JSON as a string" might mean sending raw text in HTTP body, that can happen by sending `Content-Type: text/plain` header. But it all depends on what the other side expects, and I'm not completely able to decode that from your description.

Answer (score 0):

On the body tab select Text instead of Json
[image]